# Is there a way to create bins in python instead of listing all the bin numbers (as seen in code below), and maybe without having to use np.digitize?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, bins, digitization

In my code, I have created 10 bins (specific ranges of bins are listed below):

1. 4100000-4155304
2. 4155304-4210608
3. 4210608-4321216
4. 4321216-4542432
5. 4542432-4984865
6. 4984865-5327533
7. 5327533-5670201
8. 5670201-5746217
9. 5746217-5873109
10. 5873109-6000000

    ```
    bins = [4100000,4155304,4210608,4321216,4542432,4984865,5327533,5670201,5746217,5873109,6000000]
    bin_indices = np.digitize(bins_array, bins)
    ```

Is there a way I can do this without having to list all the bin numbers (bins = [bin numbers]), and maybe also without having to use np.digitize?
Thank you very much!

Comment: There's no mathematical rule (that I can see) that defines your bin boundaries. Therefore you'll have no choice but to hard-code the 'bins' list. Of course you could write your own implementation of digitize() but why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I cant find the original author of a different SO post where I got this from using Pandas but maybe try something like this below that I thru together really fast for an idea to try. The data frame is just numpy random range to generate the fake data in the ranges you are looking for.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#create bins & categories for data ranges
cats = ['4100000_4155303',
        '4155304_4210608',
        '4210608_4321215',
        '4321216_4542431',
        '4542432_4984864',
        '4984865_5327532',
        '5327533_5670200',
        '5670201_5746216',
        '5746217_5873108',
        '5873109_6000000']

bins = [0,
        4100000,
        4210608,
        4321215,
        4542431,
        4984864,
        5327532,
        5670200,
        5746216,
        5873108,
        6000000]


def binn(df):
    df = (df.groupby([df.index, pd.cut(df['A'], bins, labels=cats)])
                .size()
                .unstack(fill_value=0)
                .reindex(columns=cats, fill_value=0))
    return df


rng = np.random.default_rng()
df = pd.DataFrame(rng.integers(4155304, 6000000, size=(1000, 1)), columns=list('A'))

dfBinned = binn(df)

print('All data binned in column A of the df')
print(dfBinned.sum(axis = 0))
```

This prints:

```
All data binned in column A of the df
A
4100000_4155303      0
4155304_4210608     35
4210608_4321215     42
4321216_4542431    130
4542432_4984864    239
4984865_5327532    174
5327533_5670200    205
5670201_5746216     37
5746217_5873108     63
5873109_6000000     75
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `numpy.arange` method:

```
bins = np.arange(4100000, 6000000, 55304)
bins
```

**Output**

```
array([4100000, 4155304, 4210608, 4265912, 4321216, 4376520, 4431824,
       4487128, 4542432, 4597736, 4653040, 4708344, 4763648, 4818952,
       4874256, 4929560, 4984864, 5040168, 5095472, 5150776, 5206080,
       5261384, 5316688, 5371992, 5427296, 5482600, 5537904, 5593208,
       5648512, 5703816, 5759120, 5814424, 5869728, 5925032, 5980336])
```

Cheers